# search for multiple values, sort by relevance (php + MySQL, no full text search)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, search, search-engine

I have a table with title and keywords columns that I'd like to search on. I want to add the ability to use multi-term search, but then it should definitely sort the results by relevance. FullTextSearch is not an option because I'm currently using MySQL5.5 and innoDB.

My current approach is as follows:

1. I search for every term individually and store matching ids in a php array.
2. Once I've searched for all terms I count id occurrences and sort accordingly.

What I'm wondering right now is if there's a more efficient way to do it as I'm primarily using php for this. Should I do some of this processing in the database? Should I change my approach drastically?

The table is relatively small (less than 10k records) and I don't expect it to become much larger in the near future.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You could probably get some help with the code if you showed it and gave some more information on your table schema and queries.

Comment: @DevlshOne: I'm using Joomla so my database interaction is kind of like pdo and I'm using REGEX (one term at a time), but I could easily change it to LIKE statements. I just didn't want some specific syntax to get in the way, what I'm interested in is if there's a way to move some of this functionality to the database so that it runs faster or if there's another, radically different approach that I should consider. Thank you, though.

Comment: See that, maybe it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35512410/1673161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the count in SQL.  Here is an example:

```
select ((col like 'term1') +
        (col like 'term2') +
         . . .
        (col like 'termN')
       ) as NumMatches
from t
having NumMatches > 0
order by NumMatches desc;
```

MySQL treats booleans as 0 (for false) and 1 (for true).  You can add them together to get the total number of matches.

Comment: O.k., this works great but I still have one question: how can I make it select only rows that match? Right now it gives me all rows, though correctly sorted by relevance! :)

Comment: You can add `having NumMatches > 0` after `from t`.

Comment: This works like a charm. I would add the `having NumMatches > 0` to your original answer. Thanks!